# including devdependencies in package.json

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, install.packages, npm-install

I'd like to generate my devDependencies based on need. For this I have an array in my generator and some operations like this:

```
var FiddleGenerator = generator.Base.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.devDependencies = [];
  },
  //...excluded for brevity
  gruntConfigure: function() {
    this.devDepedencies = [
      'grunt',
      'grunt-contrib-watch',
      'grunt-contrib-connect'
    ];        
  },
  installStuff: {
    if(this.option('skip-install')) return;
    this.npmInstall(this.devDependencies, { saveDev: true });
  }
});
```

The issue here is when the user opts to skip the npm installation and later does it manually (i.e. `npm install`) nothing gets installed.

However, I cannot simply write a package.json file like that...what versions do I put against each package in order to have them look like the following:

```
"devDependencies": {        
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",        
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the devDependencies to the package.json file manually inside the JS code (`this.fs.writeJSON`). No need to use `npmInstall()` for that.

You can see this being done here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node/blob/master/generators/gulp/index.js#L38-L69

Comment: But versions don't come against each package I use. In my code `npmInstall` takes care of it. The code you've shown extends an existing packages.json and rewrites it. It is not showing how dependencies are added dynamically via code...

Comment: Updated the example with a sub-generator adding dependencies. Anyway, the main point stays, just add them to the package.json rather than using `npmInstall`. You don't want automatic version bumps because the  your generator will generate broken code in a month or two; and that's a very bad user experience.